# background switch page load

Tags: jquery, background, switch-statement

I've seen a lot of different background switching based upon link classes, however I just want a simple background switcher on any page load (no cookies) and not link dependent.

is there a simple method for this? jquery?

Comment: What do you mean by background switching?

Comment: Page background image switching I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are looking for javascript [timers](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/)?

Example:

```
setInterval("switchBackground()", 1000);

function switchBackground( )
{
   $("body").css("backgroundImage", "xxx");
}
```

I hope this help!

**Edit:**

To generate random background at start:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //This will be random from bg1.jpg to bg10.jpg
   $("body").css("backgroundImage", "/images/bg"+GenerateNumber(10)+".jpg");

   //1 to max
   function GenerateNumber(max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random()*max) + 1;
   }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it, maybe store the instance of the interval to allow it to be cancelled. (+1)

Comment: this is right on track - however, I don't think I need intervals. I just want a random body background to load when a page loads.

Comment: Ahh i misunderstood your question. I hope the new edit is better!

Comment: great thanks @Mouhannad - also, if I add a class to this for the image (for 100% background fill) will it create any issues?

Comment: Ok, i tried adding class="background-full" to the image, and then adding a body class to the css - body.background-full {
width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;

Answer (score 3):

The code for a random background image provided by Mouhannad didn't work for me, I had to make a few small edits in order for it to function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //This will be random from bg1.jpg to bg10.jpg
   $("body").css("background-image", "url(/images/bg"+GenerateNumber(10)+".jpg)");

   //1 to max
   function GenerateNumber(max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random()*max) + 1;
   }
});
```

I needed to change the "backgroundImage" declaration to "background-image" and also added "url()" to the image path. JavaScript uses the CamelCase notation for CSS properties, jQuery does not.